# Convert any binary combination to boolean

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

I have a function that returns numpy arrays which consist of a numbers. These numbers are always two different numbers, e.g.:

```
np.array([0,3,3,0,0,0,3])
np.array([1,4,1,1,1,4,4])
np.array([0,3,3,0,0,0,3])
```

How could I convert these binary combinations of numbers to boolean, i.e. `np.array([True, False, True, True, False])`?

I've been playing around with a lot of stuff, but it seems to only work when the numbers are already 0 and 1.

Comment: what is `True`/`False` in `[1,4,1,1,1,4,4]` ?

Comment: Will you have negative integers? Can you make more examples covering edge cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
def to_bin(a):
    return a == a[:1]
```

This will give you the first value as `True` and the other as `False`:

```
to_bin(np.array([0,3,3,0,0,0,3]))
# array([ True, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False])

to_bin(np.array([1,4,1,1,1,4,4])),
# array([ True, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False])

to_bin(np.array([0,3,3,0,0,0,3])))
# array([ True, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False])

to_bin(np.array([]))
# array([], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: beautiful!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the higher number to be true:

```py
arr != arr.min()
```

Comment: This is an incorrect assumption. np.array([3,3,3,3]) will give all False.

Comment: @alec_djinn, The OP said *These numbers are always two different numbers*

Answer (score 0):

You could first check if there are only 2 unique numbers in the array and then create a boolean array using the bigger one:

```
import numpy as np

def to_boolean(arr: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    unique_numbers = np.unique(arr)
    if len(unique_numbers) != 2:
        raise ValueError("The input array must contain exactly two unique numbers.")
    return arr == unique_numbers.max()


print(f'{to_boolean(np.array([0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3])) = }')
print(f'{to_boolean(np.array([1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4])) = }')
print(f'{to_boolean(np.array([0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3])) = }')
```

**Output:**

```
to_boolean(np.array([0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3])) = array([False,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True])
to_boolean(np.array([1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4])) = array([False,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True])
to_boolean(np.array([0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3])) = array([False,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` Python's `bool` to the numpy array. In this case, 0 will be `False` while the positive integers will be `True`

```
a = np.array([0,3,3,0,0,0,3])
np.array(list(map(bool, a)))
#array([False,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True])
```

Comment: and what about `[1,4,1,1,1,4,4]` ?

Comment: It will be all True, as by the default definition of bool. If the OP wants a different behaviour, he should better specify it in his question. It is not really clear as of now.

Comment: You don't need to use a slow list/map.  `astype(bool)` converts the array directly. 
 Just subtract the smallest value first to handle the 1/4 case: `(x-x.min()).astype(bool)`